# eprime/vba highest value of 4 attributes

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

I'm using eprime (psychology software tools) to design an experiment. Within that experiment, I have 4 variables/attributes with certain values and I want to highlight the highest value out of those 4 with a rectangular. I came up with the following code, which sets the coordinates as a function of the highest of 4 values. It does work for a few simple cases:

```
If SubjTotal1 > CoSave1 And SubjTotal1 > CoSave2 And SubjTotal1>SubjTotal2 Then 
 c.setAttrib "xcoord", 785
 c.setAttrib "ycoord", 375
 c.setAttrib "border" , 10
ElseIf SubjTotal2 > CoSave1 And SubjTotal2 > CoSave2 And SubjTotal2 > 
SubjTotal1 Then  
 c.setAttrib "xcoord", 1480
 c.setAttrib "ycoord", 375
 c.setAttrib "border" , 10
ElseIf CoSave2 > CoSave1 And CoSave2 > SubjTotal1 And CoSave2 > 
SubjTotal2 Then  
 c.setAttrib "xcoord", 1730
 c.setAttrib "ycoord", 375
 c.setAttrib "border" , 10
Else
 c.setAttrib "xcoord", 1730
 c.setAttrib "ycoord", 375
 c.setAttrib "border" , 0
End If
```

However, these conditions obviously do not work for all cases, e.g. where values equal and so on. All outcomes of value-rank-relationships are possible, the could all equal, some of them could be equal while there is an individual maximum value and so on and so forth.
Thus, I actually need a smart if-statement or loop or something like that telling eprime to look for the highest of these values - if there is one - and if not, to omit highlighting. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, take a pencil and write all possible combinations on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not taking a helicopter view to determine what problem needs to be solved but instead trying to resolve things on an ad hoc basis.  This never makes for well written, easy to understand and maintainable code.

You need to find a maximum of a number of variables.  Use a function to return the position of the maximum variable in an array of parameters.

```
Public Function IndexOfMax(ParamArray ipArgs() As Variant) As Long

    Dim myIndex As Long
    myIndex = -1
    
    Dim myMax As Long
    myMax = ipArgs(0)
    
    Dim myIndex As Long
    For myIndex = LBound(ipArgs) To UBound(ipArgs)
    
        If ipArgs(myIndex) > myMax Then
        
            myMax = ipArgs(myIndex)
        
            Dim myMaxIndex As Long
            myMaxIndex = myIndex
        
        end if

    Next
    'Revised to add +1 because as we all know ,collection indexes start from 1
    IndexOfMax = myMaxIndex + 1
    
End Function
```

You now need to organise your attribute data so that the index can be used to select the set of attributes corresponding to the variable.

```
Public Function GetAttributesColl() As Collection

    Dim myColl As Collection
    Set myColl = New Collection
    
    With myColl
    
        .Add Array(785, 375, 10)
        .Add Array(1480, 375, 10)
        .Add Array(1730, 375, 10)
        .Add Array(1730, 375, 0)
        
    End With
    
    Set GetAttributesColl = myColl
    
End Function
```

You can now write some much simpler code that achieves your goal which is very easy to understand.  Note the use of an Enum to make it obvious if we misalign attributes.

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum AttributeId

    xcoord = 0
    ycoord = 1
    Border = 2
    
End Enum
    
Public Sub Test _
( _
    ByVal ipSubjTotal1 As Long, _
    ByVal ipSubjTotal2 As Long, _
    ByVal ipCoSave1 As Long, _
    ByVal ipCoSave2 As Long _
)

    Dim myAttributes As Collection
    Set myAttributes = GetAttributesColl
    Dim myIndex As Long
    myIndex = IndexOfMax(ipSubjTotal1, ipSubjTotal2, ipCoSave1, ipCoSave2)
    
    c.setattribute "xcoord", myAttributes.Item(myIndex)(AttributeId.xcoord)
    c.setattribute "ycoord", myAttributes.Item(myIndex)(AttributeId.ycoord)
    c.SetAttibute "border", myAttributes.Item(myIndex)(AttributeId.Border)
    
End Sub
```

You should be aware that if two inputs have the same value then the returned value will be the first one found.

Updated 18 July

Here's an array based solution

```
Public Sub Test _
( _
    ByVal ipSubjTotal1 As Long, _
    ByVal ipSubjTotal2 As Long, _
    ByVal ipCoSave1 As Long, _
    ByVal ipCoSave2 As Long _
)

    Dim myAttributes As Variant
    myAttributes = _
        Array _
        ( _
            Array(785, 375, 10), _
            Array(1480, 375, 10), _
            Array(1730, 375, 10), _
            Array(1730, 375, 0) _
        )
    
    Dim myIndex As Long
    myIndex = IndexOfMax(ipSubjTotal1, ipSubjTotal2, ipCoSave1, ipCoSave2)
    
    c.setattribute "xcoord", myAttributes(myIndex)(AttributeId.xcoord)
    c.setattribute "ycoord", myAttributes(myIndex)(AttributeId.ycoord)
    c.SetAttibute "border", myAttributes(myIndex)(AttributeId.Border)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant code and I think you're right, I'm not really capable of the helicopter perspective here, as I'm not very familiar with vba. I tried your code in eprime, unfortunately it did not work. I'm getting the error message "variable type expected" regarding line 1 of your second step (Public Function GetAttributesColl() as Collection). Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: I has a quick look at e-prime vba documentation.  I feel sorry for you.  I haven't seen such a useless pile of poop in a long time.  You need to check if your version of VBA supports the collection object.  If it doesn't repost here and I'll update the code using arrays.

Comment: I made a mistake with the index function so I've updated it.  I also added an array based solution in case e-prime doesn't support collections.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I tried the array based solution as I feel like collections aren't really supported. Unfortunately, e-prime seems to have a problem with the public statement- function as well. I'm getting the error message that it is expecting an argument after public (and apparently does not get one). Any ideas?

Comment: Based on your comments I'd really recommend that you work your way through a VBA tutorial and/or an e-prime tutorial so that you have a better understanding of what these keyswords and structures mean so that you can adapt them to your problem.